# High Resolution Imagery - USA

Tags: usa, geospatial

Needed a online high resolution imagery for USA free to be used anyone for personal and *commercial* purposes.

- RGB
- 2012-2015
- Full or partial country coverage
- 0,5-2 meters per pixel
- WMS/TMS and Other GIS-Services

Any suggestion?

Comment: Not an answer, but a good starting point for an inventory is the [USGS overview on aerial imagery](http://www.usgs.gov/pubprod/aerial.html).

Comment: I found Orthoimagery from The National Map. Can I freely use it and on what terms? http://raster.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Orthoimagery